# Adding a diagram in an equation

Tags: equations, diagrams

I need to reproduce this things in latex, but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could anybody help me?. My knowledge in latex is pretty basic. I have drawn the diagrams using another software.

So, is it possible to add the diagrams to equation environments?

Comment: Please try something yourself then ask what you need help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! what you try to do yourself? What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome. // We can help you, when you post code, which: a) starts at \documentclass, ends at \end{document}, b) does compile after copying it, c) shows your problem, d) leaves out all irrelevant code. Thanks

Comment: You can try to use https://www.mathcha.io/ .

Comment: Our "currency" is concrete code, not grammar or wording ...

Comment: I kindly invite to review the consistency of your criteria to close questions, because there are other questions, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558755/draw-simple-diagram-in-latex,  with even less information that remain open.

Comment: Thank you very much to projetmbc. and NBur. Both helped me a lot!!!!!

Comment: The problem was simple and pretty clearly posted. I couldn't reproduce the diagrams in latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have your diagrams already drawn, here is a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to insert a picture in an equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    Z_{BF}(\Delta) = \sum_{C_f:\lbrace f\rbrace→\rho_f} \prod_{f\in\Delta^{\star}} d_{j_f^-}d_{j_f^+} + \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}}
  \end{equation}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]